# Forms on inner product spaces, Is g an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have g be the form defined by 
g(X,Y)=Y*AX, where $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & i \\ -i & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$ I don't know how to relate the topic of forms and inner product space. Or is it as simple as prove that the conditions hold?

Comment: The exercise is to show that $g$ is an inner product?

Comment: The exercise is a question, is g an inner product or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

- Check that $A$ is a Hermitian positive-definite matrix .
- Checking Hermitian should be easy.
- You might like to check the eigenvalues are positive or the leading principal minors are all positive

Comment: Let me see, with that I could prove the third and  fourth property of inner products right?

Comment: i do not know whare are the third and fourth property but i suppose so. matrix decomposition might help in your proof.

Comment: My bad, I mean that I could prove $g(X,X)>0$ if $x \neq 0$, and $\overline{ g(X,Y)}=g(Y,X)$

Comment: yup, should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since this is just a $2\times 2$ matrix you can follow your nose and use the definition: the matrix is clearly Hermitian. Now let $$X = \begin{bmatrix} a_1+ia_2 \\ b_1+ib_2\end{bmatrix}$$with $a_j,b_j \in \Bbb R$ and compute $$\begin{align}g(X,X) &= \begin{bmatrix} a_1-ia_2 & b_1-ib_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i \\ -i & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1+ia_2 \\ b_1+ib_2\end{bmatrix} \\ &=\begin{bmatrix} a_1-ia_2 & b_1-ib_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_1+ia_2+ib_1-b_2 \\ -ia_1+a_2+2b_1+2ib_2 \end{bmatrix} \\ &= (a_1-ia_2)(a_1+ia_2+ib_1-b_2)+(b_1-ib_2)(-ia_1+a_2+2b_1+2ib_2) \\&= a_1^2+a_2^2 -a_1b_2+a_2b_1+a_2b_1+2b_1^2-a_1b_2+2b_2^2 \\ &= a_1^2 - 2a_1b_2+a_2^2 + 2a_2b_1+2b_1^2+2b_2^2 \\ &= \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & b_1 & b_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \end{bmatrix},\end{align}$$and the result follows because the real middle matrix above is positive-definite by [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) (all the principal minors are $1>0$).

--

Or you could apply Sylvester's Criterion directly for $A$, which is in fact better.